# Need to understand why laravel 8 + jwt logout without a token causes 500 internal error

Tags: php, jwt, laravel-8, php-8

Hello i created a basic laravel application (apis only) and added jwt authentication to it using 2-3 different tutorials online..

After completing all steps, we have the following routes:

```
    Route::group([
      'middleware' => 'api',
      'prefix' => 'auth'
    ], function ($router) {
      Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
      Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
      Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
      Route::post('/refresh', [AuthController::class, 'refresh']);
      Route::get('/me', [AuthController::class, 'userProfile']);
});
```

The AuthController Class has the following constructor which is enforcing the middleware to the controller except for login and register routes which don't require a token:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
    }
```

This is how the authentication defaults and guards are configured in the config/auth.php file:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

Now when i call the /auth/register route with appropriate data, the route returns 201 and a user is created successfully.

Then i call the /auth/login route using the credentials specified during the registration step, which also succeeds and returns a valid jwt token.

Now, when i use the generated token, and i use the /auth/refresh, /auth/logout, or /auth/me routes, they all function as expected.

however, if logout is called (which makes the token get invalidated) of if no bearer token is provided as authorization header, then the server returns a 500 Internal Error with the following Message.

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route
> [login] not defined. in file
> /path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php
> on line 444

It seems after logging out, or if no token is specified or token is not valid, then the middleware is calling the following redirectTo($request) function found i the authenticate middleware

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('login');
    }
}
```

However, I don't have a named login route; So, i went to my routes/api.php file and modified the /login route and named it login using the following syntax.

```
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
```

and now I'm getting a new 405 error, method not allowed.

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException:
> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
> POST. in file
> /path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php
> on line 117

As if the invalid token is forcing the middleware to redirect to the login route but as a GET method which does not exist.
What am i missing?

p.s. if i put the logout route inside the AuthControllers' constructer's except list, i get no error which makes sense. But I don't want to do that, i just want to return a json object saying unauthorized.

What I have tried, without being convinced that it's the right way of solving the problem, is the following:

First, I Created a new GET /unauthorized route and named it: unauthorized

```
Route::get('/unauthorized', [AuthController::class, 'unauthorized'])->name('unauthorized');
```

Then, I modified the redirectTo function in the Authenticate class so that it redirects to the /unauthorized route

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('unauthorized');
    }
}
```

But I'm not convinced it's the right way of solving the problem, because I don't know when does the redirectTo function gets called (I mean all the use cases) and i could have stopped something else.

Any hints on why this is happening? and what have I done wrong is appreciated!

Comment: First place to go when you see a 500 error is the server error log. What does that tell you?

Comment: This is a laravel project, no errors are logged in the httpd error_log nor any entries added to the access_log when i call any api (however when i go to phpmyadmin access_log is being logged, so i'm checking the correct files..  also i checked the laravel.log file in the storage/logs folder, and that is empty too (i actually emptied it, but nothing new is being added to it, even after reposting the logout function and getting the eerrors)